# PHP Session variable do not change in Javascript INTERVAL

Tags: javascript, php, variables, session, intervals

My SQL database get new records from several users.

Each user needs to see last records in real time. New records may produce by himself or another user.

I do not want to make every interval time traffic to write all data again. I go to check if  just have new records then write data to div.

I defined a session variable for every user to show got new records: $_SESSION['isnewr']

In PHP when get new records, then $_SESSION['isnewr'] =1; {it works good}

In PHP when write records to div, then $_SESSION['isnewr'] =2; {it works good}

In browsing file I user JavaScript interval to check for new records. At interval function I check if has new records then going to write records inside a div.

Problem: When $_SESSION['isnewr'] change in php, it freeze at Interval as "first value" got at start of running time. 
Then even there is not any new record, it write to div again and again [I am sure, because I checked loop of writing by playing sound]

Note: I can not user cookie, because several users have data entry

### File: index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = setInterval(function(){check_is_new()},3000);

function check_is_new()
{
isnewrec = "<?php echo $_SESSION['isnewr']; ?>";
if (isnewrec == "1")
{
write_all();
}

function write_all()
{
// write data to div, works good
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to make an ajax call, currently your just executing a function. And if you do that, don't use `setInterval` but `setTimeout` after your ajax call was processed. This way you don't run into any race conditions.

Comment: That won't work. `"<?php echo $_SESSION['isnewr']; ?>"` is a piece of PHP code executed on the server. The whole `<?php ... ?>` part is replaced with the actual result _before_ being sent to the browser where JavaScript executes. As far as the browser is concerned that `<?php...?>` piece of code does not exist, only the result of executing it exists, and it's the same regardless how many times you call `check_is_new`. What you need is AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in php on server is completely detached from js as soon as page is sent. So to check again if something on server has changed you need to refresh page or send ajax request.

Create dedicated page that you will request that will respond with data, if i isnewr or with predefined response e.g. "0", "-1", or "false" if there is nothing new to show.